# If C++ is backwards compatible to C, then why is void main illegal in C++?

Tags: c++, c

Or is that one of the things that C++ does not support for C?

Comment: C++ is not fully backwards compatible with C. Also, you should probably specify which C standard allows `void main()`.

Comment: `void main` is illegal in C, too.

Comment: Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027177/what-are-the-differences-between-c-and-c

Comment: To prove that C++ is **not** backwards compatible with C, here is valid C but **not** C++:   `int new =5;`  `char class, public; public = class;`

Answer (score 11):

C++ is not backwards compatible with C.

C++ *looks like* a superset of C, but it actually isn't.

Comment: To say the same thing differently: A C++ compiler will compile MANY valid C programs without complaint. It's NOT intended or guaranteed that it will compile ALL valid C programs.

Answer (score 5):

`void main` *is* illegal in C.  I don't have access here to my
copy of C90 (on paper), but C99 clearly says (concerning `main`)
"It shall be defined with a return type of int[...]".

This has been, in fact, the case since the first edition of
Kernighan and Richie.

Comment: 5.1.2.2.1 Program Startup:  "The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
parameters: [...] or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared): [...] or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-defined manner."

Comment: @JohnDibling So exactly the same in as in C99.

Answer (score 0):

`void main()` is not illegal. It's non-standard. However, a number of beginners' books on C have used void main(void) in all of their examples.

```
int main()
```

is the proper definition of main as per the C++ spec.

**Bjarne Stroustrups** made this quite clear:

"The definition void main() is not and never has been C++, nor has it even been C."

http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: An implementation *may* support <code>void main()</code> *in addition* to the standard <code>int main(void)</code> and <code>int main(int, char**)</code> signatures ("or in some other implementation-defined manner"), but it must document that additional signature.  If it's not documented, then the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @JohnDibling It requires a diagnostic from the compiler (at least in C++).

Comment: @JohnBode Where do you find that?  The return type must be `int` _and_ (one of a number of other possibilities).  In the case of C++, violations of a constraint must be diagnosed unless there is a specific statement otherwise, so a diagnostic is required.  This seems to be the case in C99 as well, although I seem to recall that no diagnostic was required in earlier versions of the C standard.

Comment: @JamesKanze: 5.1.2.2.1/1, "; or in some other implementation-defined manner".

Comment: @JohnBode So we get "The return type must be `int` and [...] in some other implementation-defined manner."  You're parsing the sentence wrong: it's "The return type must be `int` and **(** [...] or [...] or in some other implementation-defined manner **)**."  The C++ standard was originally worded the same way, but was corrected to eliminate any ambiguity (after discussion with some of the members of the C committee, to be sure that the new wording corresponded to the original intent).